# Genesis Framework - get permalink for most recent post in category

Tags: wordpress, genesis

relatively new to Genesis so hope someone can help...

I'm trying to get the permalink for the most recent post in any given category and display it on a page.  All I need is the permalink, wrapped in some text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using wp_get_recent_posts() ? You can give it arguments to filter what category you want. Take the first element, get the ID of the post and use get_permalink()

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/